wso2 custom class mediator database connection issue and external jar not picking
In wso2 integration studio i created api with custom class mediator .Class mediotor i have configured loggers and jdbc connection .while running api class mediator is picking and logs are showing in console but for jdbc connection am getting the below exception "[2024-04-11 13:39:56,579] ERROR {Cdemo} - Error while executing JDBC operation java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.apache.axis2.classloader.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:279)"
I have added external jars also but external jars not picking
need to resolve external jars not picking in class mediator in wso2 "[2024-04-11 13:39:56,579] ERROR {Cdemo} - Error while executing JDBC operation java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.apache.axis2.classloader.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:279)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at com.demo.Cdemo.mediate(Cdemo.java:29)
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassM"

Did you add the driver to the lib directory?

yeah i have added driver in the library folder

I found solution for this and in integration studio inbuilt micro integrator library folder we have to place the jdbc jar "IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\lib

It seems like your issue is related to classloading in WSO2 MI. When working with custom mediators in WSO2, you need to ensure that any external libraries (such as JDBC drivers in your case) are correctly included and picked up during runtime.
Ensure that the external JAR files containing the JDBC driver are placed in the correct location where WSO2 MI can access them during runtime. Typically, you would place them in the MI_HOME/lib directory of your WSO2 MI server.
Another approach is to bundle the external JARs into your custom mediator project. This way, the JARs will be included in the generated artifact, and you won't have to worry about external dependencies during runtime.
